# Why is there no prepend parameter in set_index?

Tags: pandas

[`df.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=set_index) has an append parameter to append columns to an existing index. But there is no prepend parameter to prepend columns to an existing index. Why is there no prepend parameter?
The only way I know to circumvent this problem is to use [`.reorder_levels()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html?highlight=reorder_levels#pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels) after using [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=set_index):

```
df.set_index('new_col', append=True, inplace=True)
df = df.reorder_levels(["new_col", "old_index"])
```

Comment: "Why is there no prepend parameter?" would be primarily a design decision and I don't know that anyone outside of the library developers would be able to answer that.

Comment: c.f. pandas issue [#26742 - ENH: allow prepending indices using set_index](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26742) and closed PR [#26724 -  Set index with prepend](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26724)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to one of the pandas devs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26724#issuecomment-500162236) (emphasis added):

> I don't think having `append` and `prepend` makes for a good API, especially since it now **doesn't cover the use case where a user may want to insert into the middle** of a multi index. Initial thought is providing `level` as an int along with `append` may make the most sense, though still not ideal IMO.

So the devs are willing to consider this type of functionality in [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), just *not* via a `prepend` param. Discussion on an appropriate API was continued in issue [#26742](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26742).

---

Also note that issue [#26742](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26742) offers a couple alternatives in addition to [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html):

- `.reset_index().set_index(...)`
- `.set_index(append=True).swaplevel(...)`
- `.set_index(append=True).reorder_levels(...)`